# Any way to snap animated TranslateTransform to pixel grid?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is there any way to snap animated TranslateTransform to pixel grid?
There is a very bad jittering, when moving text using animation. I guess it's because of subpixel positioning. I need to avoid this jittering. Suggest possible ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want `TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated"` in your XAML. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textoptions.texthintingmode(v=VS.95).aspx for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Relyea posted an article on how to [implement a pixel snapping control in Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/05/26/pixel-snapping-the-snapper-element.aspx). This is a control which listens to the LayoutUpdated event to perform pixel snapping on child elements. Perhaps this is what you're looking for; hopefully without too much modification :)

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you render thit text to `WritableBitmap` like this:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(textToTranslate, null);
```

Then place this bitmap into `Image` and translate image instead?

Comment: How to render text to the bitmap?

Comment: `WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(new TextBlock() { Text = "Some text" }, null);`

Comment: it doesn't compile. Incompatible ctor parameter.

Comment: Just create an empty project.. add `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace an then use this line `WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(new TextBlock() { Text = "Some text" }, null); `.. everithing have to be fine...

Comment: okay I get it. BTW, is there any way to achieve the same result in WPF? There is no ctor accepting UIElement there.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly? Do pixel snapping using drag'n'drop? If so, you just could call the method that does the translate if the coordinate is a multiple of a certain number.

A small example of what you are trying to do would also be helpful.

Comment: I have an animated translate transform used to make scrolling text. I need to eliminate jerks and jitter of this animated text, so I have to snap movement to pixels. Clear?